# Postgres: pg_dump gives different create statement than the one generated by PgAdmin

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4, pg-dump

Is it common to get differing create statements from pg_dump vs. PgAdmin?

Comment: Both are client programs that implement logic to reverse engineer the DDL. As `pg_dump` is part of the Postgres project, I'd consider that the reference. pgAdmin is a  separate project (just like e.g. DBeaver, Squirrel or HeidiSQL).

Comment: 1) Without seeing the actual statements how hard to say 2) Are you sure you are pointing at the same database in each case? Show the connection parameters for each. Add this information as update to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Pg_dump creates a bare table, then uses extra commands later to create the indexes, constraints, etc., even when it would be possible to do it so at creation time. This is more efficient to bulk load before those things are created, and can also avoid dependency order problems.